# Resource for learning about research funding system in the UK/Europe

Tags: computer-science, funding, europe, united-kingdom

I am currently considering to take up a tenure-track job in computer science at a UK university. I have little (i.e. no) experience with the research funding situation in Europe.

Is there any resource where I can start reading up on the research funding opportunities and the general system in place in Europe/UK?

Comment: There are databases that the unis subscribe to. A basic starting point would be to look up the reseach councils (EPSRC is my one).

Comment: For the UK, you'd be immediately interested in EPSRC and the European Union opportunities (Horizon 2020 being the main agency). Coming to the UK from abroad, you'd also be eligible for a Marie Curie Incoming grant.

Answer (score 1):

Without any experience, and without knowing your nationality (from EU or not) and your publication track; I would recommend to ask from the institute you will be working for any available fundings. Most UK universities do provide some fundings for various projects they are involved in. The best way to do this is to ask your research group manager for any recommendation.